# InDesign How does optical margin alignment really work?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography

One thing I don't understand (which would definitely help me to use this function better) is how exactly optical margin alignment really works and what exactly is measured in pt, or when to set what. Do the pt relate to the spacing at the edge for alignment or to the font size or something else entirely?

Can someone help me there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Optical margin alignment is for, essentially, hanging punctuation or glyphs.

If one has a paragraph with something along the lines of a quote internally, such as:

[image]

Note how the quote above is fairly easy to spot due its optical indent.

Turning *on* optical margin alignment will shift the punctuation or glyph to try and visually keep some glyphs aligned with the margins in an effort to compensate for their size or usage.

[image]

Note how the quote above is "hanging" rather than being aligned true left.

The dropdown list allows you to choose how far type is offset from the margins to allow for hanging glyphs.

There are a *several* articles on this if one searches the web:

- https://creativepro.com/typetalk-hung-punctuation-optical-margin-alignment/
- https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/using-type-tools/optical-margin-alignment-in-indesign
- https://creativepro.com/tip-of-the-week-using-optical-margin-alignment/
- https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-apply-optical-margin-alignment-in-adobe-ind/
- https://www.bookdesignmadesimple.com/optical-margin-alignment/
- https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1084741&seqNum=10

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So the pt of the Optical Margin Alignment are only a guide for the respective font size?